# how to pass data from directive to app.config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I have a directive widget and instead of setting theme statically in code, I wanna declare my theme color dynamically in this widget directive as with the attribute name theme and pass it to `app.config` to be able to set theme by using `$mdThemingProvider`. I have been searching for solution for 2 days now but I couldnt fix it. here is my codes

My directive code:

```
<script src="sedna-bonus-widget/widget-source.js" charset="utf-8">
</script>
<div id="sednabonuswidget">
  <div ng-controller="bonusWidgetController">
    <sedna-bonus-widget ng-model="Model" theme="c9a95a" ng-cloak> 
    </sedna-bonus-widget>
  </div>
</div>
```

my widget-directive.js:

```
var app = angular.module("bonusWidgetApp", ['ngMaterial']);

app.directive('sednaBonusWidget', function($http){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        //templateUrl: 'sedna-bonus-widget/widget-design.html',
        template: widgetDesignHtml,
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            theme: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope){
            console.log(scope)
            scope.Model = {};
            scope.Model.hotels = [];
            scope.Model.RegisterMembership = {};
            scope.Model.ActivationMembership = {};
            scope.Model.LoginMembership = {};    
    }              
})
```

I have my theme here in `scope.theme`, so how to send this to `app.config` down below?

```
app.config(function($mdThemingProvider){
   
    $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('amazingDarkPaletteName', {
        '50': 'ffebee',
        '100': 'ffcdd2',
        '200': 'ef9a9a',
        '300': 'e57373',
        '400': 'ef5350',
        '500': 'c9a95a',  // I want here to be '500': config.theme
        '600': 'e53935',
        '700': 'd32f2f',
        '800': 'c62828',
        '900': '006064',
        'A100': 'ff8a80',
        'A200': 'ff5252',
        'A400': 'ff1744',
        'A700': 'd50000',
        // By default, text (contrast) on this palette should be white with 87% opacity.
        'contrastDefaultColor': 'light',
        // By default, for these lighter hues, text (contrast) should be 'dark'.
        'contrastDarkColors': '50 100 200 300 400 500 600 A100 A200 A400',
        // By default, for these darker hues, text (contrast) should be white with 100% opacity.
        'contrastStrongLightColors': '700 800 900 A700'
    })

    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
        .primaryPalette('amazingDarkPaletteName', {
            'default': '500'
    })
})
```

```
app.factory('sharedData', function () {
    var x = "";
    return {
        'getX': function () { return x; },
        'setX': function (newVal) { x = newVal; }
    }
});
```

Comment: please see this   https://stackoverflow.com/a/35853025

Answer (score 0):

With the AngularJS framework, directives **can not** and **should not** send data to `.config` functions.

The AngularJS operates in two phases: the `.config` phase and the `.run` phase. The bootstrap loader executes all the `.config` functions before it executes `.run` blocks and instantiates directives. Thus data acquired by directives can not change the configuration of the app.

For more information see,

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Module Dependencies and Order of Execution](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#dependencies-and-order-of-execution)

---

### AngularJS Material Dynamic Themes

The AngularJS Material Design framework provides a means to implement dynamic theming with the `md-theme` and `md-theme-watch` directives.

For more inforamtion, see

- [AngularJS Material Design Developer Guide - Dynamic Themes](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/04_multiple_themes#dynamic-themes)